# Almost ring theory and derivations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-hodge-theory

I don't understand the definition of $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_A$ in the context of almost rings. In Gabber and Ramero https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409584.pdf it is covered in 9.6.12. How is $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_A$ defined? What is the difference to the usual Kähler module? I'm really sorry, but I'm lost.

Comment: I see it for the first time, but the obvious difference is that $d_A:A\to\mathbf\Omega_A$ is not additive (the formula for $d_A(a+b)$ is just before 9.6.13)

Comment: Fair, my issue is that I don't see what the definition of this object is and what the difference in the definition is.

Comment: So I tried to answer the second of your questions. Because of non-additivity it comes out bigger than the Kähler module.